# Angular Bootstrap Modal value setting inconsistency

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, bootstrap-modal

**Update 2**

```html
<div *ngFor="let c of uiVideos;let i= index" class="row curriculum-single">
    <button style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoReplace"></button>
  <app-upload-modal [id]="i" ></app-upload-modal>
</div>
```

**Update 1:**
**Here is my upload-modal.ts**

```html
export class UploadModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Input()
  id:number;

  @ViewChild('toggleButton') 
  private toggleButton : ElementRef;     
 
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  clickToggleButton() {
     this.toggleButton.nativeElement.click(); //trigger button click
  }

}
```

**And upload-Modal.html**

```html
<div class="add-popup modal fade" id="videoReplace{{index}}" #videoModal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoReplace">
  <button #toggleButton  style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoReplace{index}"></button>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header gredient-bg">
        <ul class="card-actions icons right-top">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #closeModal (click)="hideModal">
              <i class="ti-close"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Replace Video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="package_summary text-center">
          <p>Please upload a MP4 file you want to replace with the existing one. This will replace <strong>{{videosToBeReplaced?.video?.title}}</strong>
          </p>
          <p-fileUpload mode='advanced' #replaceFile name="replace1[]" [url]="getReplaceUrl(videosToBeReplaced?.video?.itemId)"
            accept="video/mp4" maxFileSize="100000000" (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" (onProgress)="onProgressReplace($event)"
            (onSelect)="onFileSelect($event)" (onUpload)="onReplaceVideo($event)" chooseLabel="Select Video">
          </p-fileUpload>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Old Code : First Question**

**Here is my component.html**

At the lower part of the code, there is a modal. Modal value is set when

`<i (click)="OpenUploaderAndBindContent(c)" title="Replace" *ngIf="c.isEditing">`

this method is clicked. As you see, there is a list drawn here `uiVideos`. For each element of this list, there is a row generating with edit, move and several actions. I have specified the action in above line code.

**Problem :**
for the first row binded from `uiVideos` are being shown in Modal. But for the next rows of the `uiVideos` are not binding to the Modal.

As you can see, I have checked the value in `this.videosToBeReplaced.video.itemId`, And they absolutely are correct for any of the rows of `uiVideos` list. but after triggering the modal, The value becomes empty.

**And below, there is the code to show the modal.**

```html
<div class="row m-3 pb-3">
  <div class="border border-success col-sm-12 p-4">
    <p-fileUpload mode="advanced" multiple='true' #fileInput name="demo[]"  accept="video/mp4" [url]="getUploadUrl()"
    (onUpload)="onBasicUploadAuto($event)" customUpload="true"
    (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)"      
    (onSelect)="onFileSelect($event)" (uploadHandler)="uploadFilesTemp($event)"
    chooseLabel="Select Videos" uploadLabel="Upload">
      <!--
         <ng-template pTemplate="toolbar">
        <div>Upload 3 Files</div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template let-file pTemplate="file">
        <div>Custom UI to display a file</div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div>Custom UI to manage uploaded files</div>
      </ng-template> -->
    </p-fileUpload>
     <p-progressBar  *ngIf="progress > 0" [value]="progress" showValue="false" mode="{{getProgressBarMode()}}"></p-progressBar> 
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let c of uiVideos;let i= index" class="row curriculum-single">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row border border-secondary rounded p-2 m-1">
      <div *ngIf="!c.isEditing" class="col-sm-12 p-1">
        <div class="lecture float-left">
          <span class="">
            <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>{{c.video.title}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="c.isEditing" class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <input [(ngModel)]="c.video.title" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" *ngIf="c.isEditing">
        </div>
        <p-progressBar  *ngIf="c.progress > 0" [value]="progress" showValue="false" mode="{{getSingleProgressBarMode(c)}}"></p-progressBar>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-12 p-1">
        <div class="row">
          <app-content-status-updater [item]="c.video" itemType="video" [isEditing]="c.isEditing" class="col-sm-4"></app-content-status-updater>
          <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 p-1">
            <select [(ngModel)]="c.video.order">
              <option *ngFor="let item of uiVideos;let i=index" value="{{i+1}}">{{i+1}}</option>
            </select>
            <i (click)="onMove(c)" *ngIf="!c.isEditing" class="fa fa-arrows p-1"></i>
            <i (click)="OpenUploaderAndBindContent(c)" title="Replace" *ngIf="c.isEditing"
            class="fa fa-upload p-1"></i>
            <i (click)="onEdit(c)" *ngIf="!c.isEditing" class="ti ti-pencil-alt p-1"></i>
            <i (click)="onSave(c)" *ngIf="c.isEditing" class="fa fa-floppy-o p-1"></i>
            <i (click)="onCancel(c)" *ngIf="c.isEditing" class="fa fa-times-circle p-1"></i>

            <i (click)="onDelete(c)" *ngIf="!c.isEditing" class="fa fa-trash p-1"></i>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<button id="videoReplaceTrigger" style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoReplace"></button>
<div class="add-popup modal fade" id="videoReplace" #videoModal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoReplace"  >
  
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header gredient-bg">
        <ul class="card-actions icons right-top">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #closeModal (click)="hideModal">
              <i class="ti-close"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Replace Video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="package_summary text-center">
          <p>Please upload a MP4 file you want to replace with the existing one. This will replace <strong>{{videosToBeReplaced?.video?.title}}</strong>
          </p>
          <p-fileUpload mode='advanced' #replaceFile name="replace1[]" [url]="getReplaceUrl(videosToBeReplaced?.video?.itemId)"
            accept="video/mp4" maxFileSize="100000000" 
            (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" 
            (onProgress)="onProgressReplace($event)"
            (onSelect)="onFileSelect($event)" 
            (onUpload)="onReplaceVideo($event)" 
            chooseLabel="Select Video">
          </p-fileUpload>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In component ts** following code determines the modals `videosToBeReplaced` value

```html
OpenUploaderAndBindContent(c: UIVideo) {
    console.log('before c: ' + c.video.itemId + ' - ' + c.video.title);
    
    this.videosToBeReplaced = new UIVideo();
    this.videosToBeReplaced = c;

    console.log(this.videosToBeReplaced.video.itemId + ' - ' + this.videosToBeReplaced.video.title);
    document.getElementById('videoReplaceTrigger').click();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

Your problem is related to the operating on the same DOM element for each iteration of for loop.

See your `OpenUploaderAndBindContent` function.

```
OpenUploaderAndBindContent(c: UIVideo) {
    console.log('before c: ' + c.video.itemId + ' - ' + c.video.title);

    this.videosToBeReplaced = new UIVideo();
    this.videosToBeReplaced = c;

    console.log(this.videosToBeReplaced.video.itemId + ' - ' + this.videosToBeReplaced.video.title);
    document.getElementById('videoReplaceTrigger').click(); <-- ISSUE 1
  }
```

You are trigger the same button for each video and eventually this will try to open the same modal. Because button is target the same modal `id=videoReplace`. Refer below snippet. `button` is targeting `videoReplace`.

```
<button id="videoReplaceTrigger" style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoReplace"></button>
<div class="add-popup modal fade" id="videoReplace" #videoModal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoReplace"  >
```

### Solution

The solution of your problem is -

1. Do not target the same `button` and `modal` by `id`.
2. You should create the multiple modal for each video so create new `modal component` say `modal-component`
3. Move the following modal content in it.

> Make the set the `button` and `model` `id` dynamic by using `@Input`.

```
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header gredient-bg">
        <ul class="card-actions icons right-top">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #closeModal (click)="hideModal">
              <i class="ti-close"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Replace Video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="package_summary text-center">
          <p>Please upload a MP4 file you want to replace with the existing one. This will replace <strong>{{videosToBeReplaced?.video?.title}}</strong>
          </p>
          <p-fileUpload mode='advanced' #replaceFile name="replace1[]" [url]="getReplaceUrl(videosToBeReplaced?.video?.itemId)"
            accept="video/mp4" maxFileSize="100000000" 
            (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" 
            (onProgress)="onProgressReplace($event)"
            (onSelect)="onFileSelect($event)" 
            (onUpload)="onReplaceVideo($event)" 
            chooseLabel="Select Video">
          </p-fileUpload>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

4.Use the `modal-component` inside the for loop

```
<div *ngFor="let c of uiVideos;let i= index" class="row curriculum-single">
   <modal-component [id]="i" ></modal-component>
</div>
```

> note : *modal-component* has the input id. This will generate the dynamic id for modal and button.

5.Finally your method will look like -

```
OpenUploaderAndBindContent(c: UIVideo, index:number) {
    console.log('before c: ' + c.video.itemId + ' - ' + c.video.title);

    this.videosToBeReplaced = new UIVideo();
    this.videosToBeReplaced = c;

    console.log(this.videosToBeReplaced.video.itemId + ' - ' + this.videosToBeReplaced.video.title);
    document.getElementById('videoReplaceTrigger'+index).click(); <-- ID IS GENERATED BY INDEX
  }
```

> Here is the id is generated dynamically.

Comment: `document.getElementById('videoReplaceTrigger'+index).click();` this is buttonid right? how is this generating?

Comment: Yes, whenever you are calling `OpenUploaderAndBindContent`, you should pass the `index` as well.

Comment: `<button id="videoReplaceTrigger" style="display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoReplace"></button>` 
but does this produce unique buttons? or I have to add index in UI Id as well? or what is the concept here? how the button id is differing?

Comment: Sing I have updated my question by separating modal and calling . please check what I am doing wrong.

Comment: And  as my modal is a child component, If I want to trigger, I have to access the child control from the parent, right? Or is there other way?

Comment: wherever you are using `id` in modal,  append the id with index. ex : `id="videoReplaceTrigger{{index}}"`

Comment: document.getElementById(...) is null. These buttons are not being find. An update again added at the top.

Comment: You can use `@ViewChild`.

Comment: I have updated your answer. I have put some changes in modal component.

Comment: If want to call the method of modal component then you can use `@ViewChild` in the parent component.

Comment: I have tried your ways bro. but its not working yet. And I had some other questions. I wanted to use same modal, as they have same structure. just few data will changed. which I will change by changing the binded data. To do so, I think, creating Modal for each indivudual, will heavy the DOM.

Comment: This is taking no where. Lets do one thing, you just create the demo in https://stackblitz.com. It will help to get the fix quicker and better.

Comment: Bro I have almost finished it. Ofcourse with your help and the concept. I will let you know when I finish. :) There were some other bussiness scenario that I could not explain here, was causing trouble. Now I figured that out. :)